# How to get form input to conform to class?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class `Submission`:

```
export class Submission {
    name: string;
    dateOfBirth: Date;
}
```

And I have the following component HTML `add-person.component.html`:

```
<div class="col-md-6 submission-container">
  <h1>Add Person</h1>
  <form [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <fieldset >
      <legend>New Person</legend>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of Birth:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="dateOfBirth" placeholder="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" class="form-control date" id="dateOfBirth">
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-success green-link">Save</button>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

...and the following `add-person.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {ApiService} from "../core/api.service";
import { Submission } from '../model/submission.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-person',
  templateUrl: './add-person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-person.component.css']
})
export class AddPersonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private router: Router, private apiService: ApiService) { }

  addForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      effectiveDate: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.apiService.createSubmission(this.addForm.value).subscribe(data => {
      this.router.navigate(['list-submission']);
    });
  }
}
```

...and this for the class `apiService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Submission} from "../model/submission.model";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/index";
import {MyResponse} from "../model/my.response";

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  baseUrl: string = 'http://www.example.com/submissions/`;
.
.
.  
  createSubmission(submission: Submission): Observable<MyResponse> {
    return this.http.post<MyResponse>(this.baseUrl, submission);
  }
}
```

The problem is that `this.addForm.value` in my `.ts` file returns on object with properties of type `string`. I need the `dateOfBirth` to be an object of `Date` class before I call `this.http.post()`.

Now, I know I could do something in `onSubmit()` like:

```
let mySubmission: Submission = new Submission();
mySubmission.name = this.addForm.value.name;
mySubmission.dateOfBirth = new Date(this.addForm.value.dateOfBirth);
```

However, the actual `Submission` class is much larger than shown here. I wish there was some way to do something like:

```
let mySubmission: Submission = Object.create(this.addForm.value as Submission);
```

Obviously, that won't work, but are there any other ways to get the properties mapped one-for-one with the correct types from `this.addForm.value` to `mySubmission`?

Comment: use <input type="date">

Comment: I don't know about your server API, but I think that sending the date in string in format yyyy-MM-dd must be work

Comment: @Eliseo, yes, but that is not the heart of the problem. I'd like to get the date into an object of `Date` class so that I can send it to the API in whatever format I desire. In the real `Submission` class there are many, many dates.

Comment: @puntacrm, isn't that HTML5 only?

Comment: @JonathanM yes.. you not use him?

Comment: @puntacrm, HTML5 wasn't a technology tagged in the question. The solution needs to be universal.

Comment: @puntacrm, or you can add that as an answer and say that it only works if using HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `html5` you can try this

```
 <input type = "date">
```

Comment: Ultimately, this didn't result in matching the class, but it did make the date in "yyyy-MM-dd" format, which was interpreted correctly into the class.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to map it one way or another.... You can do something like this....

```
export class Submission {
    name: string;
    dateOfBirth: Date;

    constructor(formValue) {
        Object.assign(this, formValue, { dateOfBirth: new Date(formValue.dateOfBirth) });
    }
}
```

then...

```
let submission: Submission = new Submission(this.addForm.value);
```